# Setting a string value to SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

How do I set Moo to the element, like this:

```
$xmlEl = new SimpleXMLElement('<Get>Moo</Get>');
```

If I initialised the element like this instead:

```
$xmlEl = new SimpleXMLElement('<Get></Get>');
```

It's something ridiculously simple. But I know it's neither addAttribute() nor addChild().

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set value of the root element:

```
<?php
  $xmlEl = new SimpleXMLElement('<Get></Get>');
  $xmlEl[0] = 'Moo';
?>
```